# Rate Limiter for Logback (i.e BurstFilter)

Tags: scala, log4j, logback

I have a lot of `warn` logs which are potentially logged on each API request, which can make huge overload due to big traffic.

I'm looking for a declarative solution to sample logs on `logback`, i.e `10%` of the logs will be printed or even better for logging mechanism that can limit the number of logs printed each time unit (`rate`)

I created the following custom filter, but I'm looking for something which exists like `BurstFilter` on `log4j` (which make `rate-limiter` and not `threshold-limiter`)

```scala
object ThresholdFilter {
  private final val LIMIT_NUM_OF_LOGS = 100
  private final val EXPIRE_AFTER_DURATION_DEFAULT: Duration = Duration.ofMinutes(1)
}

class ThresholdFilter extends Filter[ILoggingEvent] {

  final private val cache: Cache[String, AtomicInteger] = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                                                                      .expireAfterWrite(EXPIRE_AFTER_DURATION_DEFAULT)
                                                                      .build()

  def decide(event: ILoggingEvent): FilterReply = {
    if (isStarted && event.getLevel == Level.WARN && getLimit(event.getLoggerName) > LIMIT_NUM_OF_LOGS) {
      FilterReply.DENY
    }
    else {
      FilterReply.NEUTRAL
    }
  }

  private def getLimit(key: String): Int = {
    Try(cache.get(key, () => new AtomicInteger(0)).incrementAndGet()).getOrElse(0)
  }
}
```